# How did this directional derivative function change from the first expression to the second expression?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

[image]

My working got me the numerator of the second expression, but I also have a denominator unlike what is in the image

Comment: Oh, remember that $(u,v)$ is a unit vector.

Comment: For a unit vector, $u^2+v^2 = 1$.

Comment: Please transcribe sources rather than linking to an image. Images cause problems for users of screen readers and search functionalities. You can improve your question by including what "your working got". (But one guess: did you notice the word "unit"?)

Comment: Thank you everyone! I feel a bit silly now :D

Comment: @aschepler I will include that next time ;)